# Why can´t I transform a tibble to data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a tibble with information or 5 landcape metrics and 3 scales from 140 landscapes (from package landscapemetrics). Now I want to make models with it but I can´t because I can´t transform it to a data frame. 
 [I have a tibble filtered][1], but then, when I use this function:

```
MMB2 <- lapply(MMB.cls,
          function(x)
              do.call(cbind, lapply(x$data,
                                    function(y)
                                        data.frame(y$value))))
```

It says:

> "Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
>    arguments imply differing number of rows: 131, 136"

Does anybody knows whats going on? and how can I fixe it?

This is how dput(MMB.cls) looks like.

```
dput(MMB.cls) 

list(structure(list(buffer = c("1000", "5000", "10000"), data = list(
    structure(list(plot_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
    22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
    34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
    46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
    59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 
    73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 
    85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 100L, 
    101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 
    111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 
    121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 
    131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L), metric = c("ca", 
    "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", 
    "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", 
    "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", 
    "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", 
    "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", 
    "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", 
    "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", 
    "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", 
    "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", 
    "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", 
       "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca", "ca"
    ), value = c(108.110285980505, 108.110285980508, 108.110285980508, 
    108.110285980508, 108.110285980508, 193.697595715065, 112.614881229692, 
    157.660833721569, 103.605690731317, 63.0643334886277, 40.5413572426905, 
    126.128666977252, 126.128666977252, 126.128666977252, 81.082714485376, 
    166.67002421994, 166.67002421994, 40.5413572426905, 157.660833721569,
```

Comment: Just use `as.data.frame(MMB.cls)`. Also, there shouldn't be anything preventing you from building models with tibbles, as they _are_ dataframes themselves

Comment: Thanks! But I really wanna see it as a data frame, since it is easier for me. Besides, I have used it before and worked well.

Comment: You need to provide `MMB.cls` via `dput(MMB.cls)` so we can see exactly what is going on and have some data to test.

Comment: I would start by trying `as.data.frame`. But note that there are functions in some packages that don't handle tibbles. And tibbles _may_ have additional non-dataframe features such as list columns. It would help to see what MMB.cls looks like (using `dput` or `str`, not as an image).

Comment: I couldn´t paste all the `dput(MMB.cls)` but now, you can see the first part of it.

Comment: So it is advisable to reduce the data set, and then paste a syntactically complete example. Keep in mind that volunteers try to ask your question, so please improve user-friendlyness of your post.

Comment: @DiceboyT:  Tibbles *claim* to be data frames, and they're very similar, but they don't act like data frames in a few crucial cases.

Comment: The `dput` you have shared is incomplete which again makes this question not reproducible and we can't use the data. Try `dput(head(MMB.cls, 10))`

Comment: @user2554330 Sure, they have different methods for `print` and `[` and don't have rownames but they still inherit from `data.frame` -- what modeling functions would these differences impact?

Comment: @DiceboyT:  It's pretty common for packages to extract a column using `[`, relying on the default `drop = TRUE`.  Tibbles change the default to `drop = FALSE`, and the functions get a tibble instead of a vector.  A few also rely on automatic conversion of character vectors to factors.  Both of these are arguably improvements, but they mean tibbles are lying when they claim to be data frames, and other package authors have to change their packages to work around the error.

Comment: @user2554330 I can't say for sure since OP didn't actually specify what modelling function they were using, but it's unlikely for those differences to matter in this instance which was my only point

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I omited lapply function and just made one by one. 
Really, Thanks!